# How do you save data that is being produced in a handler?

Tags: ios, swift, accelerometer, core-motion

The handler code (in this case, collecting accelerometer data) is being executed asynchronously when my accelerometer moves.

That means if I try to save `data.x`, `data.y`, `data.z` in a variable, even if the variable is declared outside of the handler, the variable will be `nil` if I attempt to print it anywhere.

How do I save this data to access in other parts of my code?
(Or does everything have to happen in my handler, best-practices wise?)

```
    if motionManager.accelerometerAvailable{
                    let motionQueue = NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()
                    motionManager.startDeviceMotionUpdatesToQueue(motionQueue,
                    withHandler: gravityUpdated)
    }
 func gravityUpdated(motion: CMDeviceMotion!, error: NSError!) {
        let grav : CMAcceleration = motion.gravity;
        println(grav.x)
  }
```

Comment: Can you post some of your code?

Comment: Yeah! I normally find the problem to be more conceptual rather than on a code-level (which tends to obfuscate things), but sometimes code helps illustrate an example! Just posted a short function. I want to save grav.x.

Comment: You may need to save the data in some property and the invoke some function (or post a notification) that there is data to be processed. Exactly what action you take depends upon what you want to do with the data. let's say you wanted to update a plot with the new data - you could invoke a function with the reading that added the data to an array property and the refreshed the graph. If you wanted to sound an alert if the reading was above some threshold then you could invoke a function that simply compared the value, played a sound if required and then discard the reading.

Comment: (Continued) all of this needs to happen in the handler or in code invoked by the handler (or some other handler alerted by, say, an NsNotification from the handler). Event-driven processing is an important concept in modern programming. Apps use this heavily - rather than running lots of linear code, your app runs code in response to events - touches on UIElements, sensor updates, network notifications etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main thing to be wary of is that these events can come in more quickly than the main thread can process them. As the documentation says:

> Because the processed events might arrive at a high rate, using the main operation queue is not recommended.

Hence, you should your own background queue to handle these events.

Regarding how you then use this updated information on the main thread, there are two considerations:

1. To ensure your code is thread-safe, any variables that you use both from this background thread and other threads must be synchronized.
2. Make sure you don't just dispatch updates back to the main thread. I would generally create a dispatch source of `DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_DATA_OR` or `DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_DATA_ADD`, put a handler for that source on the main queue, and then your `motionQueue` can then then perform a `dispatch_source_merge_data` on this source.

   GCD will then coalesce these data changes, notifying the main thread when there were updates, but not backlogging the main thread in the process.

---

By the way, you may also want to review Table 4-1 of the [Event Handling Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/motion_event_basics/motion_event_basics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH6-SW14), which outlines common update intervals for acceleration events (measured in Hz), depending upon the intended usage:

> - 10–20: Suitable for determining a device’s current orientation vector.
> - 30–60: Suitable for games and other apps that use the accelerometer for real-time user input.
> - 70–100: Suitable for apps that need to detect high-frequency motion. For example, you might use this interval to detect the user hitting the device or shaking it very quickly.

You might want to choose a `deviceMotionUpdateInterval` commensurate with your application's needs.